# tablet + wired network + recharging

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, battery, tablet, kiosk

Can any tablet simultaneously recharge and use a non-wireless network?

The goal is like an always-on kiosk-like touchscreen, in a location that forbids wifi.  Ethernet (*not* Internet) would be e.g. 192.168.10.xxx to a file server.  Static IPv4, not DHCP.

The challenge is that (micro-)USB to ethernet adapters, such as those made by Apple and others, tend to use the the same USB port as a recharger.  I'm not afraid to solder fine-pitch connectors into a custom adapter, but I do have distaste for Qi-compatible wireless chargers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, even if it's more difficult that simply "soldering" two pins (which will burn either the tablet, the charger, or both, unless protection kicks in). Due to this difficulty, "dual mode" adapters are rare, and not all models can be supported -- but some do exist.

[This](http://lavalink.com/products/tablet-usb-adapters-poe-usb-lan-hubs/usb-host-charging-adapter-for-samsung-galaxy-tab/) is one model by Lava for Galaxy Tab 2; they have also different models.

See also [this other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34741/can-an-android-tablet-serve-as-usb-host-and-be-charged-simultaneously-through-a) for details of the difficulties and possibly circumventing same.

And in a few weeks you might see something [here](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1094775787/port-power-usb-at-the-same-time).

Comment: Yes, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/43568/39439 suggests that a cable and a resistor suffice.  Much simpler than the kickstarter "+port".

Comment: UPC 884840046219 is an Asus gizmo that turns USB into USB + ethernet, "for when you don't have wifi," for Asus Transformers.  $10 to $20 instead of Lava's $45.

Comment: That seems to come from [http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/batt_charging_1_1.zip] "Battery Charging Specification" 1.1, 2009-04-15, page 29. But it seems much more complicated to me (for example it refers there to *three* resistors, of which the third only is 36.5K); the reference on Wikipedia is no longer there, apparently. And anyway, that's if we're dealing with a OTG A capable device.